# Is it possible to save a data flow task to an independent file?

Tags: ssis, dataflowtask

In SSIS, I should save a part of control flow to another file and take it when needed. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this using the "Execute Package Task"

1. Take the relevant part of your control flow and put it into a brand new package.  This will be your "child" package.
2. Back in your original "parent" package, add the "Execute Pacakge Task" to your control flow.
3. Configure the Execute Package Task to point to your saved child package from step #1.